# Should you use preprocessing directives in .NET (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to stop my .NET code from sending emails when im in debug mode, just to safeguard a bit so I'm not sending emails out when im debugging.

Is it fine to just use `#if DEBUG` or is there an interface I can inject into my class? I always like to do things the proper way if I can so is there any industry standard way of going about this?

Code for reference:

```
#if !DEBUG
    _mailHelper.sendEmail(email);
```

Comment: Using `#if DEBUG` is a common and straightforward way to conditionally disable certain functionality, when your code is in debug mode. This approach is widely used and acceptable in the industry. It allows you to easily control whether specific code blocks are included or excluded based on the build configuration.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use a preprocessor directive for this. Instead, I'd just have a different SMTP config for local testing where the emails still get "sent" but instead go to disk instead of an actual email. That way you can still check the emails are working. Either way, this is an opinion-based question so not on-topic here.

Comment: It Depends. Wouldn't you want to disable emails during testing or staging? Wouldn't you want to test email integration at some point?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DavidG, that is a good idea. I am sending emails via the microsoft graph api but I dont see why I could say if in debug, send to localhost instead

Comment: Good point @PanagiotisKanavos, I think I will introduce a config setting for this and inject IConfiguration. As you say, its really only production that should be sending emails externally

Comment: In principle it's perfectly fine to enable/disable certain behaviour based on preprocessor directives. But in the given usecase I'd probably use a setting in the app-config instead. Because now, if you for instance want to debug an error in your mail sending or enable it because of some reason, you would have to recompile your project ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your approach is perfectly valid.

Another common approach is to have some configuration (for instance, coming from your `appsettings.json` file), that varies between your environments (local, CI, production...). In fact, there's a "native" support for this in .NET: [Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

One naive approach would be to check that configuration in the place where you perform the email sending, and perform different actions depending on it:

```cs
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    _mailHelper.sendEmail(email);
}
else
{
    // Send mail to local testing server?
}
```

A better approach, if you are using a dependency injection container, is to instead inject a different implementation of your `IMailHelper` depending on the environment:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IMailHelper, FakeMailHelper>();
}
else
{
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IMailHelper, MailHelper>();
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you perform the environment check just once, during the startup of your app. Therefore, it becomes closer to the `#if DEBUG`, but cleaner and more flexible (although maybe harder to follow).